# microsoft.reportviewer.webforms remove inline style sheet

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm currently trying to use `ReportViewer` in `VS 2012`.
I'm using the dll `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`.

My problem is that I want to write all the style using `css-classes` but all the inline styles is hopless.

Is there a way to remove all the inline styles in this control?

Comment: please dont suggest me by Page_Load event to assign properties

Comment: I think your only two options are:
1) Use Javascript/Jquery to remove the styles that the ReportViewer Control adds at render-time (upon the report being loaded).
2) Do what you said not to suggest and add/override them on the page_load event.